# Group by with where clause where both expressions have to be correct?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a table `products`, `artists` and `artist_product`. It's possible to that a product is from multiple artists, so the `artist_product` table would say

```
id = 1
product_id = 1
artist_id = 1

id = 2
product_id = 1
artist_id = 2
```

What I now want to have is to get all products that have been manufactured by the same artists. So all products that are from both `Artist 1` and `Artist 2` but not someone else (e.g. a 3rd artist)

Let's say I have artist 1 and artist 2 as in the "table" above explained. I'm looking at product with id 1. Now I want to have all other products that are by the same artists (e.g. product 2, 3, 4 etc.) but not from other artists and not the current product.

I wrote this query

```
SELECT p.title, ap.product_id 
FROM artist_product ap 
INNER JOIN product p ON p.id = ap.product_id 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Now I get all the products that have more than one artist, correct? But the problem is, that I'm now only getting products from multiple artists, I now need to check the artists, too. I can't do `artist_id = x AND artist_id = x` because that wouldn't work because of the group by, and I also can't do `artist_id = x OR artist_id = x` because that would not be the same.

I would need to solve this problem, and also need to know how I would solve this in Doctrine? I currently don't have a class for `ArtistProduct`, would I need to create one and do it like this?

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('\namespace\Product')->createQueryBuilder('p');
$artists = $this->getArtists();
$qb->innerJoin('ap.artist_product', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.id IN (:artists)')
    ->setParameter('artists', $this->getArtists())
    ->setMaxResults(12);
$qb->andWhere('p.id != ' . $this->getId());
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This doesn't look right, there must be something I'm missing here. Normally I would go and first create the Query in SQL, and **then** create the Query in Doctrine, but I don't even get the query right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, ap2.product_id, count(*) c
-- first select what we want - product
FROM product p 
-- it must have both artists
INNER JOIN artist_product ap 
  ON p.id = ap.product_id AND ap.artist_id IN (?, ?)
-- catch any other artist
LEFT JOIN artist_product ap2
  ON p.id = ap2.product_id AND ap2.artist_id NOT IN (?, ?)
GROUP BY p.id 
-- and exclude the product, if it has one
HAVING ap2.product_id IS NULL 
-- there must also be exactly 2 artists
AND c = 2;
```

Comment: This looks promising. Am I simply replacing the question marks with the IDs of the artists in both cases? Also in the group by the product_id is ambigious, should I use `ap` or `ap2` here? And further, the table `artist_product` doesn't have the column `id`, it simply exists of `product_id` and `artist_id`. I upvoted you for the effort, if we can solve the remaining stuff together I'll accept

Comment: group by product_id was an error, it should be p.id. I also realize I did not include match on 2 artists, updated. 1st and 3rd ? is first artist, 2nd and 4th ? second artist id.

Comment: This looks like it would be working, awesome! Is this possible with doctrine also, or should I use a native query?

Comment: It seems you will be able to use DQL, instead of ON use WITH.

Comment: Hey, I already used it with a native raw query and the resultsetmapper and it works superb!